# My website looks fine on my computer, however zooms in on the text on other computers

Tags: html, css, zooming, screen-resolution, browser-support

I'm a experienced web designer who has seemed to met my match with this bothersome problem. The basic rundown is my website I'm making for a client is completed and runs efficiently as well as looks the way I want it to on my computer.

When I view it through other computers however, my navigation bar disappears. I was able to find out that the page was apply a "zoomed in" effect through inspect element, and found that at 75% the text and navigation bar appeared the way it was supposed to be arranged.
When viewed at 100% however, all my text and nav bar seems to either disappear entirely or appear in a more disorganized fashion. While zooming to 75% places it in the right layout, I don't know whether or not the zoom function will be the real answer to my problems.

Alas, I don't know how to fix this and was hoping somebody could help me out.

My website works with vertical parallel scrolling (achieved with Jquery). Below I've listed the overall div screen CSS as well as the CSS for the first screen/landing page (all other screens have the same CSS).

```css
div#slideTrain {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
div#screen1 {
    background-image:url("photos/landingpage3.jpg");
        no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Here are the CSS parameters for the navigation bar, under the id name "controls"

```css
div#controls {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    margin-top: 860px;
    margin-left: 630px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    overflow: hidden;
}
span {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

The HTML part of the controls are as follows:

```html
<div id="controls">
    <span id="button1">home</span>     
    <span id="button2">our team</span>     
    <span id="button3">menu</span>      
    <span id="button4">contact</span>
</div>
```

This is my first time using this website so I apologize in advanced if I missed any protocols or input things incorrectly. I've provided two screenshots of the main page, both how it should look and how it has been appearing on other computers.

The correct format, with the nav bar located on the bottom.
[Correct Format](http://tinypic.com/r/33f3w9e/8)

The incorrect format, where the nav bar is only visible when scrolled down but still remains misaligned (all text on other pages also misaligns).
[Wrong Format](http://tinypic.com/r/1zox9wg/8)

Comment: Please format the code properly. providing it in jsfiddle is more helpful to troubleshoot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, K. Chunga. Unfortunately the code provided does not reproduce the problem. Please create a Snippet and add all necessary code to replicate the problem, or add a link to a website. Edit the question instead of commenting, please. Thank you :)

Comment: You have an error in the CSS for the background image. It should either be the shorthand `background: (all the properties);` without semicolons inbetween, or all the properties written out in full, like `background-image: (url); background-repeat: no-repeat; etc`